# Deleted Recovery partition (T2 chip Macbook pro). Can not boot to recovery. Getting Error -2003f

Tags: macbook-pro, disk-utility, startup, recovery

I have been trying for a few days, but I have not been able to get my mac into Recovery mode. I formatted the laptop and erased data from Mac utility also deleting macOs base system, the recovery partition. I bought the Macbook Pro 2019 used. Last time it had my iCloud id. I wanted to resell it. Now I have tried more than 20 times to get into recovery <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. I get error -2003f sometimes similar -1000f. 1005f (different number of same error) and it keeps failing after loading for few minutes. Tried with 2 different WiFi networks, but with the same issue.

[image: Mac-error]

I looked at Youtube videos and internet postings mentioned to boot via USB but can't boot, it displays a "stop" screen. In some forum its mentioned that boot through usb might be disabled. It's getting really frustrating. I have been trying for a week and no fix.

Does anyone have any Idea? I am in a country where there is no Apple store unfortunately. Any suggestion how to fix this?

[image: Prohibit stop sign error]

Comment: Do you have a second Mac available?

Comment: Yes I do have access to another mac. @pion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out what was causing the issue. The country I am in has some strict censorship and as a result apple server was blocked from accessing.

**METHOD 1 :**
I downloaded a VPN and Shared VPN over WiFi Hotspot, connected through the VPN-enabled wifi and the recovery was successful.

**METHOD 2:**
Incase method 1 doesn't work, and if you have access to second macbook pro, you can run Apple Configurator restore or revive software. [More here](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/apple-configurator-2/apdebea5be51/mac)

Appreciated everyone's help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Fix with following steps in this article

https://portallaptop.com/blog/2831/2022/05/02/macbook-error-2003f/